# Add rows in a dataframe based on a elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the below list & dataframe:

```
lis = ["Color", "Material", "Handle"]

Code for dataframe:

data = [[1, 'Color', 'Yellow', 'SourceA'],
        [1, 'Material', 'Plastic', 'SourceA'],
       [1, 'Handle', 'Y', 'SourceB'],
       [2, 'Color', 'Blue', 'SourceB'],
       [2, 'Handle', 'N', 'SourceA'],
       [3, 'Color', 'Black', 'SourceA'],
       [3, 'Color', 'Black', 'SourceB'],
       [3, 'Material', 'Steel', 'SourceA']]
  
df_one = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Id', 'feature', 'feature_value', 'Source'])
```

```
df_one = 

| ID | feature  | feature_value | Source  |
| 1  | Color    | Yellow        | SourceA |
| 1  | Material | Plastic       | SourceA |
| 1  | Handle   | Y             | SourceB |
| 2  | Color    | Blue          | SourceB |
| 2  | Handle   | N             | SourceA |
| 3  | Color    | Black         | SourceA |
| 3  | Color    | Black         | SourceB |
| 3  | Material | Steel         | SourceA |
```

I need each ID to have all the features listed in "lis". ID1 has "Color", "Material", "Handle" but ID2 does not have "Material" and ID3 does not have "Handle". I need my output to look like the below:

```
| ID | feature  | feature_value | Source  |
| 1  | Color    | Yellow        | SourceA |
| 1  | Material | Plastic       | SourceA |
| 1  | Handle   | Y             | SourceB |
| 2  | Color    | Blue          | SourceB |
| 2  | Handle   | N             | SourceA |
| 2  | Material | null          | UNK     |
| 3  | Color    | Black         | SourceA |
| 3  | Color    | Black         | SourceB |
| 3  | Material | Steel         | SourceA |
| 3  | Handle   | null          | UNK     |
```

I tried iterating through the rows of the dataframe and creating a dictionary of each row but because the ID column is not unique, I didn't have a unique key for key & value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that *at least* one `ID` has the three values of `lis`, [`DataFrame.complete`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete) is for you.

```
#pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
​
out = df_one.complete("Id", "feature", fill_value={"Source": "UNK"})
​
```

Output :

```
df_one.groupby("Id")["feature"].agg(set).eq((lis)).any()
#True

print(out)

   Id   feature feature_value   Source
0   1     Color        Yellow  SourceA
1   1  Material       Plastic  SourceA
2   1    Handle             Y  SourceB
3   2     Color          Blue  SourceB
4   2  Material           NaN      UNK
5   2    Handle             N  SourceA
6   3     Color         Black  SourceA
7   3     Color         Black  SourceB
8   3  Material         Steel  SourceA
9   3    Handle           NaN      UNK
```